# How to handle certain SonarQube wrongly recognize rules?

Tags: sonarqube, metrics

I am using SonarQube 4.5.4 and it works quite well for certain rules. However there are some rules that show a rule violation where there should not be one. namely *Unused private method should be removed*. I have some private methods that are defined in a class. These methods are called from an .fxml file as FX object.

Is there a way I can teach SonarQube to learn this exception?

Further one of the method in question has an parameter which is marked as unused by SonarQube but the parameter is necessary for FX action events.

I would be very glad if anybody could help.

Here is a piece of the code:

```
@FXML
    private void scanList(ActionEvent aEvent) {
      superObject.scanCurrentListAction();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've run into this:

https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1179

As a workaround, you can enable or disable rules in Sonar via the rules administration UI.  You can also set up company or project specific rule sets and assign them to your projects.

Comment: thank you Hdave. this is what I feared. I guess I will just keep the rule active and check by one by one if the rule applies or it belongs to an FX object.